# How to redirect both stdout and stderr to file AND still output ONLY stderr?

Tags: file, shell, logging, stdout, stderr

How can I redirect the output of a command such that both stdout and stderr gets logged in a file, AND I still want stderr to appear as output.

I also don't want to use bash for doing this. Is there such a way?

Comment: Usually shells do redirection. So when you say you don't want to use bash, what shell DO YOU want to use.

Comment: For bash see [Redirect stdout and stderr to file and stderr to stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24001720/905686).

Answer (score 3):

That is very easy:

```
$ ( ./command.sh >> log ) 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

You write the stdout of command to the `log` file in a sub shell; than you write 
stderr to pipe; and than, my means of `tee`, save it to the `log` and copy the same to the console.

Example of usage:

```
$ cat command.sh               
#!/bin/sh

echo out
echo err > /dev/stderr

$ ( ./command.sh >> log ) 2>&1 | tee -a log
err
$ cat log
out
err
```