# Redirect stdout and stderr to file and stderr to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, cron

The following writes stdout to a logfile and prints stderr:

```
bash script.sh >> out.log
```

This again writes both stdout and stderr to a logfile:

```
bash script.sh >> out.log 2>&1
```

How to combine both features, so that stdout and stderr are logged to a file and stderr is emailed to my inbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bash script.sh 2>&1 >> out.log | tee -a out.log
```

First, I'm redirecting **stdout** to file and **stderr** to **stdout** (**stdout** line gets to the *out.log* file and **stderr** to pipe).

The `tee` command prints **stdin** to both **stdout** and file (resemblance with the letter *T*). Thus second, I'm printing the original **stderr** to both **stdout** and the *out.log* file (the `-a` argument means *append*).

Comment: The only problem with this is that it seems like lines may get reordered, since you now have two processes outputting to the same file.  I see no way around this though.  I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @pacholik, thanks! It's interesting (and counter-intuitive) that `2>&1 >> out` get stderr to | while `>> out 2>&1` gets it to out

Answer (score 0):

You can keep stdout in a separate file and stderr in separate file:

```
0 * * * * bash script.sh > out.log 2> err.log
```

and then email yourself `err.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
./myscript.sh &> all.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

- `&> all.txt` to have both `stderr` and `stdout`
- `2> stderr.txt` to have only `stderr`

And then just do whatever you want with those files, such as email logging for instance!

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work.  Stderr will only go to stderr.txt, and not to all.txt.

Comment: Are you sure of this ? It worked when I tried. Unless it is a zsh-only functionnality ?

Comment: Ah I see, it does work in zsh.  In bash it definitely does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using process substitution you can try:

```
0 * * * * bash script.sh >> out.log 2> >(exec tee >(exec cat >> mail))
```

Or

```
0 * * * * bash -c 'exec bash script.sh >> out.log 2> >(exec tee >(exec cat >> mail))'
```

`exec cat >> mail` imitates mailing. Replace it with a command that actually does the mailing.