# Dupplicating STDOUT filedescriptor in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have scripts which write text (`stdout`) and error-messages (`stderr`) - and both I want to save to log files. The order of `stdout` and `stderr` must be preserved! But during runtime - I'm only interested in the printed text (`stdout`).

There are different [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002019/494725), e.g.:

```
bash script.sh 2>&1 >> out.log | tee -a out.log
```

...but I found none which preserves the order or `stdout` and `stderr`...

This is the `myscript.sh` which I used for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo out1
echo err1 >&2
echo out2
echo err2 >&2
echo out3
echo err3 >&2
echo out4
echo err4 >&2
exit 7
```

The only way I know to get `stdout` and `stderr` written in the correct order to a file is `&>` - is there a way to **dupplicate** stdout before?

Imaging `1>&3` would dupplicate stdout to fd3 - instead of redirecting - this would be the idea:

```
./myscript.sh 1>&3 &>logfile 3>&1
```

PS: I'm using dash by default - bash would be OK too.

Comment: Stdio implementations alter their buffering behavior according to whether their output is a terminal or not. The only way to preserve the order would be to run within a separate pseudo-terminal and capture the output of that terminal.

Comment: @PSkocik, how does the separate-pty approach allow stdout and stderr to be distinguished? If you're routing through `tee` to log content to stderr or stdout before *getting to* the pty, you're back in the same problem space.

Comment: *All* redirections duplicate the file descriptor -- they make the destination FD a copy of the original one, and thus cause it to write to the original FD's destination. That's the only kind of duplication that UNIX filesystem semantics allow; you fundamentally can't have a single `write()` going to more than one destination without having something `read()` it and then do one additional per-destination `write()`... thus introducing the synchronization problem that those additional writes are happening *after* the original, "real" one did.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. Brute force solution. Run the process twice.

```
./myscript.sh &> out.log & # Output stdout and stderr in correct order to log file
./myscript.sh 2> /dev/null # View stdout on terminal
```

Or a oneliner:

```
./myscript.sh &> out.log | ./myscript.sh 2>/dev/null
```

2. Another brute force solution; Simply put time stamps on the output messages and redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to separate files to be merged together at a later time.
   Use this script to generate the two logfiles:
   `./myscript.sh > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> stderr.log`

You may want to take a look at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering?noredirect=1&lq=1) for some *ugly hackery*